# Connect to device ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, i have to develop a web page that connects to a fingerprint device using its SDK (C# SDK), captures fingerprint image and display live preview from the device.

This page is working fine if the device is connected to the server that hosts my page.

The problem is when a client opens the web page and connects the device, the code that is written to connect to the device runs on the server so it doesn't detect client devices (Device SDK is installed on the server, so it detect device only if it is connected to the server).

Can i run device code on client side using c#?

Comment: Do the clients have a device on their side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who need help: I implemented a custom way to connect to USB devices connected to client workstation from ASP.NET MVC web pages.
Using [Web Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), you can create your own client desktop application (c#) to connect to the device. This desktop application will be a Server for Web Sockets and then in your web page, you can implement a Web Sockets client to connect to the desktop application.

**Client Sample (JavaScript)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/service");

    ws.onopen = function ()
    {
    };
</script>
```

**Server Sample**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wssv = new WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8080);

            wssv.KeepClean = true;

            wssv.AddWebSocketService<Service>("/service");

            wssv.Start();
            if (wssv.IsListening)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on port {0}, and providing WebSocket services:", wssv.Port);
                foreach (var path in wssv.WebSocketServices.Paths)
                    Console.WriteLine("- {0}", path);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter key to stop the server...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            wssv.Stop();
        }
```

More about Web Sockets in JavaScript: [Html 5 Web Sockets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm).

Also, a good c# Web Socket Library: [C# Web Sockets](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't be able to access the device directly from code running in a web page. Some device manufacturers do make certain APIs available from the web (camera, GPS, etc), but only in a limited fashion. It's highly unlikely that you'd be able to access an arbitrary third-party device from a web site unless it can act as a standard input device (keyboard or mouse) and interact with an input element.  For example, if it could fill a text box with a string corresponding to the fingerprint or allow you to take a picture of the fingerprint which could then be uploaded through a file input, then you might be able to use it.

The alternative is writing a secured plugin - Java Applet or ActiveX control - that accesses the device natively and use it to interact via JavaScript with your web page.  User's would have to allow the plugin to be loaded and let it have permission to access the device for it to work.

Comment: Would Silverlight be a valid option in this case?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure what the limitations on accessing native devices is in SilverLight.  Beyond the technical issues of getting it integrated, I would also be concerned about the ability for a remote user to spoof the technology and provide any fingerprint.  I wonder if you wouldn't be better off using some sort of 2-factor authentication - say like a password and a code that you send via SMS to their phone for secure authentication.

Answer (score 1):

[Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) is a plugin available for some browsers that allows you to run .NET (C#) code on the client. It is similar to Adobe Flash or Java Applets. The development is somewhat similar to developing a WPF app.

Things I would be concerned about are whether you can access the device or not due to security restrictions. Also, see tvanfosson's comment on his own answer. It should be relatively simple to throw together a basic "Hello, world!" app to verify if you can talk to your device from Silverlight.

Another concern is that the last Silverlight support may not be top priority for Microsoft, and it has limited support on non Microsoft platforms.

Another technology you might consider is a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application.